# Old Venue 8 tablet. Missing keypad

Tags: factory-reset, tablet, android-device-manager, hard-reset, gboard

My daughter thought it would be cool to put a Russian keyboard on the Venue tablet. She didn't uninstall it correctly and now no keypad shows up. We cannot unlock it. I have tried going to the Play Store and uninstalling the keyboard, but I can't see how to. I have tried a hard reset but can't get the "dead android" to show up for the reboot menu. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Three options.

1. Use a USB-OTG adapter with a USB keyboard to unlock the device via password. Or a keyboard with a built-in OTG adapter.
2. Since you obviously have a Google Account, log into [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager), and wipe the device through there.
3. A Hard Reset via Recovery. Unlike some other Android devices, the Dell Venue 8 requires you press and hold **Volume Down**, press and hold power, then release power when you get the first logo. Do not release Volume Down until you see the Droidboot menu. Choose Recovery, and from there wipe data/cache and reboot. That's a Hard Reset, ***ALL your data will be erased***.